# Imagens com content-type como text/html, como resolver?

Tags: php, content-type

Estou fazendo um foreach no controller para testar se está retornando todas imagens o problema é que as imagens não aparecem pois o content-type está como text/html, quando estou utilizando o método index do controller não tem problema, todos arquivos incluídos no html tem seu content-type correto, o erro também está acontecendo no css.

[image: Imagem com content-type: text/html]

```
<?php

  use app\models\Images;

  Class Home{

  public function index(){
    include 'app/views/index.php';
    $images = new Images();
    foreach ($images->all() as $key => $value) {
      echo '<img src="app/views/imgs/'.$value->name.'">';
    }
  }

  public function add(){
    $name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
    $image = new Images();
    $image->setName($name);
    if($image->insert()){
      $image->upload();
    }
  }

  public function img(){
    include 'app/views/index.php';
    $images = new Images();
    foreach ($images->all() as $key => $value) {
      echo '<img src="app/views/imgs/'.$value->name.'">';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Deve ser algum .htaccess em sua pasta, ou pode ser que a pasta `/Home/app/views/imgs/...` é incorreta

Comment: Ah sim o 'Home' é o controller e ele esta vindo antes do app no caminho da imagem na verdade ele nem deveria estar ali, o certo era está apenas app/views/imgs/..., muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que seja erro de digitação, pois as imagens estão acessando isto:

```
/Home/app/views/imgs/...
```

Ao invés disto:

```
/app/views/imgs/...
```

Corrigindo:

```
public function index(){
  include 'app/views/index.php';
  $images = new Images();
  foreach ($images->all() as $key => $value) {
    echo '<img src="../app/views/imgs/'.$value->name.'">';
  }
}

...

public function img(){
  include 'app/views/index.php';
  $images = new Images();
  foreach ($images->all() as $key => $value) {
    echo '<img src="../app/views/imgs/'.$value->name.'">';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sim é isto mesmo mas não é erro de digitação, acontece que a request url para buscar essa imagem fica incorreta dependendo do caminho que eu colocar no src, isso por causa dos controllers, métodos e parâmetros passados na url, o request entende que ambos são pastas para acessar a imagem.

Comment: Erro de digitação é uma maneira de se referir que faltou algo no código ou sobrou.